# How to set classification colors in GDAL output files

Tags: c++, gdal

I am using the GDAL C++ library to reclassify raster map images and then create an output image of the new data.  However when I create the new the new image and open it, the classification values don't seem to have a color defined, so I just get a black image.  I can fix this by going into the image properties and setting a color for each of the 10 classification values I'm using, but that is extremely time consuming for the amount of maps and trials I am doing.

My question is, is there a way to set metadata info through the GDAL API to define a color for each classification value?  Just the name of the right function would be great, I can figure it out from there.

I have tried this using ArcGIS and QuantumGIS, and both have the same problem.  Also the file type I am using is Erdas Imagine (called "HFA" in GDAL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SetColorTable()](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723222834/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALRasterBand.html#a8198cc415555b2942a4a35fe6ed19ef3) method on your raster band.  Easiest to do is to fetch one pre-existing raster using [GetColorTable()](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723222834/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALRasterBand.html#a2c5cad0f0fc1b6e261d1e965a5b49969), and pass it to your new raster.